# Why won't an .Play() work on an <embed> .mov?

Tags: javascript, embed, .mov

in html:

```
<EMBED SRC="movies/test.mov" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="100%" AUTOPLAY="false" CONTROLLER="false" LOOP="false"PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/" id="movie1" />
```

in javascript:

```
document.getElementById('movie1').Play();
```

the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLEmbedElement> has no method 'Play'
```

Yet it works fine with the same javascript from the JS console, what is going on?

Comment: Can you post the full URL to your .mov file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a space between `LOOP` and `PLUGINSPACE`. Othewr than that, I can't find any problems. It may be the way you're calling the JavaScript, or maybe the URL is wrong. It's working here: http://jsfiddle.net/8GYLZ/. I used a sample `.mov` file from the Apple site, and called it with a button.